# mysql query if col1 has repeat value but col2 is different

Tags: php, mysql

### Sample table layout

```
|  col1  |  col2  |  col3  |
----------------------------
|  ab    |  12    |  02:20 |  
|  cb    |  11    |  03:30 |
|  ab    |  12    |  03:40 |
|  cb    |  11    |  03:45 |
|  ab    |  13    |  03:50 |
```

---

so what i want to pull is anytime col1 repeats itself but col2 is different, i would also like to only pull results for the last hour, so with the sample table and the time of the day being 4:00 the output of the query would be

```
ab 12 3:40  
ab 13 3:50
```

Comment: what sql statement have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MyTable.col1, col2, col3
FROM MyTable
     INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT col1
      FROM MyTable
      GROUP BY col1
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2) > 1) t on t.col1 = Mytable.col1
WHERE col3 > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl1.col1, tbl1.col2, tbl1.col3 
FROM tbl AS tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl AS tbl2 
    ON tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1 AND tbl1.col2 != tbl2.col2
WHERE col3 >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, I think the following should do what you need:

```
mysql> select * from testTable;
+------+------+----------+
| col1 | col2 | col3     |
+------+------+----------+
| ab   |   12 | 02:20:00 | 
| cb   |   11 | 03:30:00 | 
| ab   |   12 | 03:40:00 | 
| cb   |   11 | 03:45:00 | 
| ab   |   13 | 03:50:00 | 
+------+------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select col1, col2, MAX(col3) maxTime from testTable where col1='ab' group by col1, col2;
+------+------+----------+
| col1 | col2 | maxTime  |
+------+------+----------+
| ab   |   12 | 03:40:00 | 
| ab   |   13 | 03:50:00 | 
+------+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(EDIT - Per clarification in the comments, I believe the desired answer involves no where clause)

```
mysql> select col1, col2, MAX(col3) maxTime from testTable group by col1, col2;
+------+------+----------+
| col1 | col2 | maxTime  |
+------+------+----------+
| ab   |   12 | 03:40:00 | 
| ab   |   13 | 03:50:00 | 
| cb   |   11 | 03:45:00 | 
+------+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yes that would do what i need on that small sample, the db is more complex and has close to a million rows, so i cant just key off of one specific value in col1, because there are going to be lots of values that could be in that column not just 'ab', sorry should of made that clear in OP

Comment: Then just remove the "where col1='ab'" and you're all set.

Comment: Also, just FYI... If you need a different output than what you are asking in your question it would help to include this information in the question itself (you can edit it for clarity), it will make it easier for others to help you reach a correct answer more quickly that way.  Thanks.